# Orchard - how to access taxonomy field of a custom content type programmatically

Tags: orchardcms

I have a custom content type called `Store`, which has a `Brands` taxonomy field. A `Store` can have multiple `Brands` associated with it.

I have been tasked with building an import/export routine that allows the user to upload a CSV file containing new `Stores` and their associated `Brands`.

I can create the Stores other fields OK, but can't work out how to set the taxonomy field?

Can anyone tell me how I access the Taxonomy field for my custom content type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since Orchard supports import out of the box (including a specific import procedure for taxonomy terms), wouldn't the simplest be to convert your custom csv format to the standard Orchard import format and import the results?

Comment: Thanks @BertrandLeRoy, never thought of it that way. Unfortunately I don't have the time to learn the Import/Export stuff, but one for next time. I'll post my alternative solution shortly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so (as Bertrand suggested), using the Import/Export feature might be a better way to go, but as a relative noob on Orchard I don't have the time to spend looking at it and couldn't find a good tutorial.

Below is an alternative approach, using the TaxonomyService to programatically assign Terms to a ContentItem.

First of all, inject the `ContentManager` and `TaxonomyService` into the constructor...

```
private ITaxonomyService _taxonomyService;
private IContentManager _contentManager;

public MyAdminController(IContentManager contentManager, ITaxonomyService taxonomyService)
{
     _contentManager = contentManager;
     _taxonomyService = taxonomyService;
}
```

Create your ContentItem & set the title

```
var item = _contentManager.New("MyContentType");
item.As<TitlePart>().Title = "My New Item";

_contentManager.Create(item);
```

Now we have a ContentItem to work with. Time to get your taxonomy & find your term(s)...

```
var taxonomy = _taxonomyService.GetTaxonomyByName("Taxonomy Name");
var termPart = _taxonomyService.GetTermByName(taxonomy.Id, "Term Name");
```

Add the terms to a List of type `TermPart`...

```
List<TermPart> terms = new List<TermPart>();
terms.Add(termPart);
```

Finally, call `UpdateTerms`, passing in the ContentItem, terms to assign and the name of the field on the ContentItem you want to update...

```
_taxonomyService.UpdateTerms(item, terms.AsEnumerable<TermPart>(), "My Field");
```

Hope this helps someone. Probably me next time round! : )